# Accessing form data form JSON object converted to associative array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I'm sending the HTML FORM data with AJAX to PHP script and I'm converting the data to associative array like this:

$json = json_decode($request->get('json'),true);

so, when I'm dumping the variable I get this array:

```
array(11) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(21) "form[pickupDate][day]"
    ["value"]=>
    string(1) "4"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(23) "form[pickupDate][month]"
    ["value"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(22) "form[pickupDate][year]"
    ["value"]=>
    string(4) "2016"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(22) "form[pickupTime][hour]"
    ["value"]=>
    string(1) "0"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(21) "form[returnDate][day]"
    ["value"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
  [5]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(23) "form[returnDate][month]"
    ["value"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
  [6]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(22) "form[returnDate][year]"
    ["value"]=>
    string(4) "2016"
  }
  [7]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(22) "form[returnTime][hour]"
    ["value"]=>
    string(1) "0"
  }
  [8]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(19) "form[pickupAddress]"
    ["value"]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
  [9]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(12) "form[agency]"
    ["value"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
  [10]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(12) "form[_token]"
    ["value"]=>
    string(43) "9dh6ghpMv5K9LUdSLvh6y2NOzqTzUrOfVriL8C63Ybs"
  }
}
```

how can I get the value of form[pickupDate][day] without loop?

Comment: use $json[0]['value']. considering json fromat will not change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do it like this:

echo array_column($json, null, 'name')['form[pickupDate][day]']['value'];